# Buying ex-local authority/council properties in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, risk

What are the risks of investing in ex-local authority/council properties in the UK? 
I am referring to purchasing from a private landlord an apartment that was built by a city council for social housing in the 1960s-1990s (and then sold it off with right-to-buy schemes). Typically, these properties are part of larger estates and are leaseholds. The council still owns the ground.

For example, there are a lot of ex-council apartments in London in central locations for 30-40% less than on the "normal" real estate market.
I read about the following risks as a landlord:

- Anti-social behaviour on the premises
- Regeneration: Councils might purchase the property back to demolish it with compulsory purchase orders (typically to license the land to private developers).
- Costs of compulsory maintenance work (for example changing cladding)

Any other risk?

**EDITED**: added clarification

Comment: Anti-social behaviour can exist around (almost) any property type across the UK, not just around ex-local authority/council properties.

Comment: Are you talking about *recently* ex-council properties, or ones that used to be council owned decades ago?

Comment: Make sure you know the exact year of the build and whether it may contain brown asbestos, as this could turn out to be a maintenance nightmare later on: http://asbestosvictimadvice.com/2016/01/asbestos-in-council-homes-another-social-housing-crisis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buying an ex-council property, like any home, comes with its own risks and rewards. As your question is asking for the risks, The biggest risks can include:

- [Not all mortgage lenders will loan on ex-local authority homes](https://www.homesandproperty.co.uk/property-news/buying-an-excouncil-house-in-london-are-they-good-value-for-money-which-are-the-best-areas-to-buy-in-a115696.html)
- [Some people have found selling ex-local authority homes challenging](https://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/showthread.php?t=2750054)
- [Location also has a lot to do with it](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2007/sep/12/firsttimebuyers.property)

Because there are often negative stigmas attached to council estates in the minds of buyers, it can be tricky to resell at a good price.

For example, Winkworth's estate agents found that "prices are roughly 30% lower for ex-council." but there is, again, an "ex-council stigma".

The same article mentions liability: When buildings become 100% owner-occupied, the owners tend to set up a management committee. If there is a mix, however, the council will be in charge -- this is also something you'd need to consider before purchasing and could be considered a risk to some.

Answer (score 2):

A big risk for a council apartment is that the building will need substantial work done on it in future.  This could include major renovations because the building is substandard.

Rent-paying tenants don't have to pay for the work, the landlord does.  But if you buy a long lease on an apartment, you become liable for your share of any building work.